# Factorize a prefixed parameter with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got several routes for my Express router:

```
router
.post('/:id/foo/*', func1)
.get('/:id/bar/*', func2)
.post('/:id/foobar/*', func3);
```

All those routes share the "/:id/" prefix and I would like to know if there is a more compact and elegant way for writing this.

The goal would be to write something like:

```
router
<something to capture de /:id/ and pass the subroutes to the following functions>
.post('/foo/*', func1)
.get('/bar/*', func2)
.post('/foobar/*', func3)
```

Is a wrong/good/feasible idea?

Comment: What are your reasons for wanting to optimize this?

Comment: to simply not repeat myself

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the language but can you do something like: `.post("/:id/[foo|bar|foobar]", func)`?

Comment: It would require to maintain a "dispatcher" function. I think I prefer to repeat the "/:id/" in each route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Express 4.5+ you could use a [`Router`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router):

```
// mergeParams allows parent params to be passed down to child routes
var router = express.Router({
  mergeParams: true
});

router
  .post('/foo/*', func1)
  .get('/bar/*', func2)
  .post('/foobar/*', func3);

// Mount router at `/:id`
app.use('/:id', router);
```

You can also use [`app.param`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param) if you wanted to preprocess the `id` param before the other middleware which would also negate the need to merge the params from parent to child.

```
// No need to mergeParams as `res.locals.id` will be populated
//  by app.param middleware
var router = express.Router();
router
  .post('/foo/*', func1)
  .get('/bar/*', func2)
  .post('/foobar/*', func3);

app.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
  // ... do some logic if desired ...
  // assign the id to the res.locals object for downstream middleware
  res.locals.id = id;
  next();
});

app.use('/:id', router);
```